# How to limit the frame rate in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I know that the present mode of the swap chain can be used to sync the frame rate to the refresh rate of the screen (with `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` for example).

But is there a way of limiting the frame rate to a fraction of the monitor refresh rate? (eg. I want my application to run at 30 FPS instead of 60.)

In other words, is there a way of emulating what `wglSwapIntervalEXT(2)` does for OpenGL?

Comment: It does not make all that much sense in a world where the monitors can dynamically change their refresh rate....

Comment: Can all the monitors do that? And can I choose the refresh rate programmatically? If not, then it makes sense in my use case.

Comment: Not through Vulkan ATM I am afraid. The way it is designed ATM is that you are in charge of timing. I.e. do not present something that you do not want displayed ASAP. If you have 60 Hz monitor it might make sense to make use of it though -- e.g. it seems it is beneficial to insert a black frame, rather than show the same picture twice.

Comment: There is no way to do that from the Vulkan API perspective. But You can do it on Your own - make CPU busy enough so frame generation takes more than 17 ms. If You present swapchain images after such a period, FIFO mode will display them on screen 30 times per second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vulkan is a low-level API. It tries to give you the tools you need to build the functionality you want.

As such, when you present an image, the API assumes that you want the image presented *as soon as possible* (within the restrictions of the swapchain). If you want to delay presentation, then *you* delay presentation. That is, you don't present the image until it's near the time to present a new image, based on your own CPU timings.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing when or how many vblanks happened? I may be able to manage with timings, but to get the exact behavior of swap interval, vblank info would be great.

Comment: @Jerem: Vulkan doesn't have a mechanism to ask those questions. However, you don't need to; if you want to limit your FPS to 30, then you use a CPU timer to keep yourself from rendering/presenting a new frame for that period of time.

Comment: @Jerem Not at the moment. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/370 is relevant here I think.

Comment: Well technically there is `VK_EXT_display_surface_counter` extension, but the spec implies it may be only for `display_swapchain`, and [Vulkan HW DB](https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php) shows 0 support. Or `VK_GOOGLE_display_timing` but only limited support (only on some Android).